# C++ WriteProcessMemory Doesn't work in 32 bit

Tags: c++, winapi, memory

The Question is in the title 
im using write process memory to change some values in memory
i tried it in 64 bit windows and its works perfectly
but the problem is in 32 bit windows it doesn't write the value i want
read process memory works in 64 bit windows and 32 bit windows but the problem is in writing
please help me (:

Edit:
Code is :

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <windows.h>
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    cout << "Loading..."<< endl;
    int address = 0x3458CBC0; 
    int address2 = 0x3458CBC4; 
    int value = 20;
    DWORD pid;
    HWND hwnd = FindWindowA(NULL,"some window");
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd,&pid);
    HANDLE phandle;
    cout << "Found Proccess ID:" << pid << endl;
    phandle = OpenProcess(0x1F0FFF,0,pid);
    cout << "Loaded Successfully."<< endl ;
    ReadProcessMemory(phandle,(LPVOID)address,&value,4,0);
    cout << "Readed Value:" << value << endl;
    ReadProcessMemory(phandle,(LPVOID)address2,&value,4,0);
    cout << "Readed Value:" << value << endl;
    address = 0x3458CBC0; 
    address2 = 0x3458CBC4; 
    value = 20;
    WriteProcessMemory(phandle,(LPVOID)address,&value,4,0);
    WriteProcessMemory(phandle,(LPVOID)address2,&value,4,0);
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

**Solution** :

The application hooked the apis of writing in memory in the kernel
the hook does'nt work in 64bit Windows so i can write to memory

Thanks everyone!

Comment: 32 bit process is trying to write to 64 bit process?

Comment: Are you asking if `WriteProcessMemory` is buggy?  Or if your code is buggy?

Comment: im asking if there a method to make the write process memory works in 32 bit windows

Comment: How about a code example of something that works in 64-bit, but doesn't work in 32-bit.  As well, say if you're writing from/to 32-bit, 64-bit, etc.  More information please.

Comment: @H2CO3 WinAPI works perfectly fine. What are you talking about?

Comment: Your code doesn't explain what the actual problem is. You're writing to two different locations and reading from a third. What exactly isn't working?

Comment: sorry i put wrong code,edited

Comment: is there another method to write memory to another process ?

Answer (score 2):

A 32-bit app running under Windows is really using a special 32-bit emulation wrapper (WOW64). You can't write to the address space of 64-bit applications from there.

[Here's a page that explains it better than I can.](http://www.techsupportalert.com/content/how-windows7-vista64-support-32bit-applications.htm)

**Edited to add:**

If you're doing a 32-bit build, running on 32-bit Windows, it should work. If it doesn't, please post your code.

**Edited to add:**

Test the return value of `WriteProcessMemory()`. If it's zero (which seems likely), call [GetLastError()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679360%28VS.85%29.aspx) -- that should give you a clue.

Comment: the application i want to change its memory is 32 bit
and the windows is also 32 bit

Comment: its win 32 console application builded using VS 2010 using windows 7 x64

Comment: when i copy it in another computer that use win xp x32 writing doesnt work.

Comment: you are right it return 0,GetLastError ?? it return 4294967295

Comment: You absolutely *can* write process memory from a 32-bit process to a 64-bit one. You just are limited to writing within the 4GB addressable range of that 64-bit process (i.e. only to pointers less than 0x00000000`ffffffff). 64-bit processes can write to both x64 and WOW64 (32-bit) processes.

Comment: understand so the write process memory in 32 bit is limited.. thank you every one

Comment: but some programs supports this why ??